# legality of streaming data on 868 or 915 Mhz in EU/US

Tags: esp32, rf, stream

From what I read about duty cycles in the EU there is a 10% limitation (even less in some sub bands).
The modules I found have a max. rate of 300 kbps. Even if you max out the duty cycle that would only be 30kbps.

How do consumer devices like a digital walkie talkie operate here legally in the EU?
What am I missing?

Is there a frequency where I can legally stream constantly at more than 70kbps (not Wifi) ?

Comment: Anything in the 2.4GHz band. There's more than just WiFi that works at that frequency.

Comment: 868MHz and 915MHz are ISM (Industrial, Scientific and Medical) bands which has both power and throughput limitation. It is designed for short burst of data, not for streaming as it is a shared resource. For walkie talkie, it operates on other unlicensed band like sharing the band with WiFi on 2.4GHz. If you need the bandwidth, use 2.4GHz.